# Color-Based Segmentation Using K-Means Clustering

Tags: image, matlab, colors, k-means

Hi i found this tutorial about segmenting colors from images in

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

There is a part there wherein the colors has been segmented into 3 part

specifically this part of the code

```
    for k = 1:nColors
     color = he;
     color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
     segmented_images{k} = color;
    end
```

Now the output is partitioned into 3 separate colors

IE.

image 1 contains only blue

image 2 contains only yellow

image 3 contains only brown

now what i am asking is how can i just get the brown partition? In my example the position of the brown color is 3 but sometimes when i partition other images, The position of the brown color becomes 2. How can i determine what color goes to which partition when using the LAB colorbased segmentation?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you know the color, you can always convert to HSV and check its range of H. H is Hue, or "color".

Comment: You can use the duplicate.  Once you find the centroid / mean RGB colour value of each cluster, you can use the procedure in the duplicate to determine what colour it belongs to, and thus what colour the centroid represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mean of each group to decide and compare it to a standard mean that you define. That way, you can algorithmically define which classified group is close to your "brown" group and use the brown color for it.